# Implementing in python

Tags: python, oop

I am pretty new in Python. I would like to implement a program in an object-oriented form. In the end, I like to use the objects of a class in this format.

```
ObjectA.add.func1()
```

I am not sure what kind of structure I need to use for `add`? If whether it is another object inside another object?

The functionality of my program should be like this:

`add` is object or something else that I will pass some functions to it. It will contain those functions.
at the end, I will call forexample `ObjectA.apply()` and it will apply all functions to the object. The object can be vector of floats. I also open to any suggestion, what should `add` be? but I like to use the `add` in the instruction form I mentioned.

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: It sounds like `add` need to return something callable. Hard to say more given the question.

Comment: thank you I havn't implemented anything. I am just looking for an answer to what if I want to implement precisely this instruction. What add could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it'd be an object that is a member of another object.  Something like:

```
class Adder:
    def func1(self):
        pass

class MainObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.add = Adder()

object_a = MainObject()
object_a.add.func1()
```

As an aside piece of advice: it's better to figure out what your code will do before you figure out what "shape" it will have.  Trying to force your program logic into a particular OOP model before you know anything else about what you're trying to do is likely to make your life more difficult, whereas the goal of OOP should be to make it easier.  :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I got the idea what add can be :)